# Populate an array and loop through vertical headers for table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to populate an array from a list of names in a table to generate vertical headers in a table.

I'm using a foreach loop to show when someone is available for each day of the week and have days across the top as a horizontal header and their names (from a seperate table) I want as a vertical header down the left side of the table.

My table code is as follows;

```
    <?php 
    $person = print_r($name_array); 

    foreach($rota_sun as $rota_sunday): ?>
        <tr>                    
            <th scope="row"><?php echo ($person); ?></th>
            <td data-title="SUNDAY">


            <?php if(strpos($rota_sunday['person_name'], $escort) !== false) { ?>
                <span style="color:green; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <span style="color:red; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <?php } ?>
</td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My code for the query is;

```
$query = "SELECT id, name from persons"; 
try 
{ 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$name_array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong - the array is getting populated I can see that through a `print_r` but I cant seem to incorporate it correctly with my existing foreach loop.

Comment: Tables are generally generated how we read, top to bottom, left to right. Model your code to account for that. I'm still a little hazy as to exactly what you're asking, though.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? I see you are missing some closing tags in that loop.

Comment: Also th is for table header, td is for table data. It doesn't make sense to have both in the same row.

Comment: If I were doing this I would do it all in php and return  string.

Comment: I wouldn't, @SamOrozco. PHP is a mark up language. You don't need to encapsulate everything in an echo statement. He just needs to think about how he organizes his data before echoing it out.

Comment: @Blake I have added in some closing tags - I only extracted a snippet of my code, there is a section for each day of the week. The table is a rota so a persons name on the left with which day they work to the right with a column for sunday, monday etc...

Comment: @Ben Your query seems to just give a list of people. How do you know if they're working that day? `$escort` isn't in your code at all. Sounds like you need to set up some logical looping. A row of days, a row for a person, check if person works on Sunday, Monday, etc..

Comment: @Blake I want to pass the array to a variable that if it matches a column value it displays a tick or an x. That works when I manually enter the value with my current set up - I'm just not sure how to bring the array into the rota_sunday / rota_monday / etc foreach loop. $escort has become person - just a typo here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue and loop through a list of names to generate a vertical header as required.

Screenshot - http://prntscr.com/cf60sf

Snippet of final code;

```
<?php foreach ($escort_names_array as $escort_name_array) : ?>
<tr>                    
<th scope="row"><a href="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>girl/<?php echo($escort_name_array['escort_name']); ?>/"><?php echo htmlentities($escort_name_array['escort_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></th>
                        <td data-title="SUNDAY">
                            <?php foreach($rota_sun as $rota_sunday): ?>
                            <?php if(strpos($rota_sunday['escort_name'], $escort_name_array['escort_name']) !== false) { ?>
                                <span style="color:green; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <?php // } else { ?>
                                <!--<span style="color:red; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>-->
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>                        
                        </td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```